# Lightview chart histogram like Highcharts Stacked bar

Tags: lightweight-charts

Is there any way I can make a Lightview histogram chart with multiple values per data point, so that it looks like a Highchart stacked bar (https://www.highcharts.com/demo/bar-stacked)?
If not, is there a workaround?
I already overlay-ed two separate histograms, but that does not help, because both start at the bottom and depending on the values some points are hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not possible to draw vertical histogram at the [moment](https://github.com/tradingview/lightweight-charts/discussions/778).

Comment: I was afraid my example would be misunderstood. I don't need a vertical histogram.
I just need the ability to set multiple values per data point.
In the example, the number of apples is the sum of Joe + Jane + John
My use case is showing different types of events that occur in a timeframe. For example logins + logouts in 1 day intervals

Comment: Apologies for misunderstanding your question.

Would that example answer your question?
https://jsfiddle.net/romainfrancois/bm35czpg/9/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately that's not what I need. For example for time 1643202922, the red value is 46 and the blue value is 16. In this case, I would like a column 62 units long with the first 46 units red and the next 16 units blue.
Would that be possible?

Comment: I'm guessing it's not possible, though. I found this issue https://github.com/tradingview/lightweight-charts/issues/761 that basically says that.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not something we offer and it's not planned either.